# git cherrypick, merge, rebase or otherwise, with long-lived branches/topics

Tags: git

There is lots of good advice to ponder about cherry-picking (using this term in the abstract here: not the actual command, per se) in SO already, but all that I have read so far seems to assume that the branch/topic from which commits are coming will immediately die. The rebase route seems to require that you give up on the branch. In the explanations of other approaches, dropping the branch after the action is implied by the structure of the responses. but nothing is explicitly stated about it.

one-liner: I have a fix that needs to get into production before the topic branch will be done; the same fix needs to also be in the branch for the work there to be viable.

This would applies to cases where production and test (or whatever) branches co-exist for long periods, as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To make this concrete let's say we have a master branch with production code and your work branch which you want to keep ready to push to master. One of the commits on your work branch is the hot fix that needs to be applied. The master branch only reflects the state of the remote origin/master until you are ready to push changes.

You pull on master to get your master up to date then you rebase your work branch based on master moving your hotfix to the start of your commit list.

```
git checkout master
git pull
git checkout work
git rebase -i master
```

Then you can then go to master and cherry pick the hotfix commit and push it.

```
git cherry-pick *commit*
git push
```

What really helps here is that the master branch is clean and always represents the last updated version of the remote origin master.

Comment: I am marking this as the correct answer only because it is more complete. The branches could be reversed and so match the other answer given so far (by timwolla). Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I would apply that hotfix to the branch that topic branch is branched off and merge the base back into the topic branch / rebase the topic branch instead of cherry picking it from the topic branch. This makes it clearer that the commit is no specific to that one branch, but a general purpose fix that solely was found while working on the branch.

Comment: I choose to do this, but marked a different answer as correct just for it's completeness. The two answers just reverse the branches AFAICS. Thanks